# Do I need to publish application to test in app purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I was working on in app billing last time about 1 yesr ago. In that time to test in app billing I was need to setup tester account, upload application in draft mode and publish purchases.
Since then Google added "sandbox" mode (which allows to test purchases without money transactions) and I want to use it.  I've read documentation but for me it's parts contradict each other.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases) it says that I only need to upload the app (nothing about publishing), add purchases and test accounts. Which is similar to the old mode. But it also says that alpha-testers WILL pay money for purchases.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps) it says that "draft" mode is unsupported so I need to publish my app to Alpha testing. Nothing about setting up alpha-testers list.

So my question is if I need to publish my app to alpha-testing mode to test purchases without money transactions?

P.S. Can I still use IABHelper from demo application? Examples in the documentation doesn't use it anymore.

**UPDATE** Docs says that purchases may be published before the app. But developer console says that purchases will be activated only after application is published.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to publish to alpha or beta (which won't be visible to the public). You do not need to publish to production

What I do is publish to beta with an .apk and install that same .apk on testing devices via side loading (no downloading and installing from the playstore when in beta)

Comment: And again answers contradict each other:)

Comment: why via side-loading (pbuliched for alpha testing app is viisble for alpha testers) and you're not paying for purchases?

Comment: I've always side loaded on my own personal device, didn't realize it would be visible to testers. Guess we both learned something today :)

Comment: @MobilMon do you use IABHelper class from demo application?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to publish your app... you can keep it unpublished but you've to upload apk there..

Comment: And again answers contradict each other:)

Comment: but there's actually no "draft" state anymore.