# Trying to query in-app billing product but no luck , can you make queries to in-app billing products when you are in Draft mode?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I know as of May 2015 google changed how they handle your app in draft mode -

> In a few cases, you can test Google Play functionality with an unpublished app. For example, you can test an unpublished app's in-app billing support by using static responses, special reserved product IDs that always return a specific result (like "purchased" or "refunded").

My question is can you use IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync() on your prouducts in draft mode. I know to do a purchase you have to use reserved product id but what about query? This question stems from the fact that I am returning null when I get Inventory back from my Listener.

```
        final String SKU_VERBAL_HINT = "verbal_00.thisthat";
            // compute your public key and store it in base64EncodedPublicKey
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d("Issue", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
            }else{
                //List<String> additionalSkuList = new ArrayList<String>();
                //additionalSkuList.add(SKU_VERBAL_HINT);
                String[] moreSkus = {SKU_VERBAL_HINT};
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, Arrays.asList(moreSkus),
                        mQueryFinishedListener);
                Log.d("Issue", "No Problem setting up in-app billing " + result);
            }
        }
    });

            mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error
                return;
            }

         **-------->FAILS HERE, null inventory**  String verbalPrice =
                    inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_VERBAL_HINT).getPrice();
            String verbal2 = verbalPrice;
            // update the UI
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer. Draft apps are not supported.

> BlockquoteDraft Apps are No Longer Supported
>   Previously, you could publish a "draft" version of your app for testing. This functionality is no longer supported. Instead, there are two ways you can test how a pre-release app functions on the Google Play store:

You can publish an app to the alpha or beta distribution channels. This makes the app available on the Google Play store, but only to the testers you put on a "whitelist".
In a few cases, you can test Google Play functionality with an unpublished app. For example, you can test an unpublished app's in-app billing support by using static responses, special reserved product IDs that always return a specific result (like "purchased" or "refunded").

> Blockquote

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24866513/2192015

From this is sounds like the app has to be published to the alpha or beta channel to do testing.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps

Comment: @ Heureux  Last paragraph of developer.android link you posted says that you can test without publishing in cases where you use static response in in-app billing, which is what I am doing. The stack overflow link is somewhat correct. It needs to be published only if you are doing non-static purchases.

Comment: "You do not need to list the reserved products in your application's product list. Google Play already knows about the reserved product IDs. Also, you do not need to upload your application to the Developer Console to perform static response tests with the reserved product IDs. You can simply install your application on a device, log into the device, and make billing requests using the reserved product IDs."  This makes me think that if it is not published, nothing will be queried.

Comment: My understanding from reading the docs is that you have to upload a signed APK file, so that you are able to do in-app billing testing. So when you say upload your application are you referring to a signed APK file? Also have you seen code that uses these reserved product ID? I imagine it looks something like this -         mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,android.test.purchase,RC_Request,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload); With "android.test.purchase" being the reserved product ID